# Скрытия следов get с двумя пременными

Tags: .htaccess

Не могу сделать переадресацию с двумя переменными в get запросе.

С этого:
**shop.loc?category=games&page=2**

На это:
**shop.loc/games/2**

Comment: не хотите ли показать, как вы пытались это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По данному примеру (без каких либо доп.условий) будет так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=(\w+)&page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2? [R]
```

Comment: Извините, но я неверно выразился. Нужно не переадресацию осуществить, просто сделать так, чтобы на этой странице запросы отражались красиво, без следов get (shop.loc/games/2), но при этом данные из гет были переданы и была отображена страница shop.loc.

Comment: @zimzum так, давайте теперь я спрошу: вы хотите набрать в строке браузера это `http://shop.loc/?category=games&page=2`, нажать `Enter`, после чего увидеть в браузере "красивую" строку `http://shop.loc/games/2`, но чтобы при этом браузер не отсылал серверу новый запрос GET?

Comment: Да, все верно. Я просто хочу чтобы в адресной строке выглядело все красиво. Чтобы отобразилась страница "shop.loc" и чтобы ей были переданы $_GET['category']='games' и $_GET['page']='2'.

Comment: @zimzum сомневаюсь, что это можно решить стороной сервера и модулем mod_rewrite. Как вариант, можно попробовать жаваскриптом вот так: `window.location.href = "games/2";` после обращения к url: `shop.loc/?category=games&page=2`

Comment: Спасибо большое за консусльтацию. Буду и дальше разбираться в этом вопросе пока не найду удовлетворяющее мой случай решение. Вы мне крайне помогли советом.